# Tooltip showing junk values on hover - SSRS reports

Tags: random, reporting-services, charts, tooltip

Tool tip in SSRS is showing random junk values when hovered over chart area or even sometimes on the data points or plots. Here are some images to illustrate the issue. My question is - is this a bug in ssrs or are there some property settings I can set or is it actually related to my data.. Please help. Many Thanks!
PS: Sorry couldn't add the images because of reputation constraints.

Comment: You can add links to the images and someone with higher rep will generally edit them into your question for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Chris for the suggestion. I found the solution for this question. Next time onward I'll follow  that.

The Solution:

The junk values of tooltip were nothing but values that had either been set or had got set at various levels of the chart- chart area , plot area, series etc. I just had to remove all except the series tooltip. It works fine now.